# Difference and practicality of pointer vs. any-pointer media features

Tags: media-queries, interaction-media-features

The documentations on [`pointer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/pointer) and [`any-pointer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/any-pointer) read pretty similar, as testing whether the user has “a” or “any” pointing device doesn’t make a difference in the scope of this media feature, does it?

I tried the following CSS …

```css
@media (pointer: fine) {body{background:green}}
@media (pointer: coarse) {body{background:red}}
⸻
@media (any-pointer: fine) {body{background:green}}
@media (any-pointer: coarse) {body{background:red}}
```

… both on a notebook with a connected mouse, and only with its touchpad, as well as a smartphone with only its touchscreen, and with a connected mouse.

In all scenarios, the desktop yielded “fine” (even with its coarse? touchpad) and the smartphone yielded “coarse” (even with a fine? mouse connected), whereas I anticipated:

- `any-pointer` should have yielded `fine` on the smartphone with the mouse connected
- `pointer` should have yielded `coarse` on the notebook with only the touchpad available

I hope I just don’t grasp it just yet, but otherwise … is it a bit quirky? Or what are practical scenarios for `pointer`/`any-pointer` respectively in regard to style usage and user hardware?
(Why would one need both?)

Comment: Same question here. Actually, the **only** reason i stumbled upon *these* media queries was to detect **whether a touch device has a mouse connected**.  *Btw, how would it detect whether a different input would be course or fine anyway?*

Answer (score 2):

`pointer` refers to the **primary** input, while `any-pointer` refers to whether **any** such pointer is attached to the device.

Smashing magazine has [an article](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2022/03/guide-hover-pointer-media-queries/#media-queries-any-hover-and-any-pointer) which exemplifies it well:

> The first one is a cellphone that has a keyboard and a mouse connected
> via Bluetooth, while the primary pointer device of this cell phone is
> a touchscreen, the addition of a mouse adds an accurate pointer to it.
>
> The second one is a mini wireless keyboard that can be used for
> devices like Smart TVs, X-Box, or even mobile vehicle TVs. Smart TVs’
> are not very accurate, but this control has a touchpad that adds an
> accurate pointer to this device.
>
> What do those two elements have in common? Both of them won’t be
> detected by the previously mentioned media queries [using `pointer`], because both of
> them detect the primary input mechanism. How do we detect those cases?
> This is where once again CSS brings us two more tools to help us:
> media queries any-hover and `any-pointer`.